# How to merge two bitmaps with specific shift(offset)?

Tags: c#, c++, c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

Let say we have two bitmaps that are represented by unsigned long(64-bit) arrays. And I want to merge this two bitmaps using specific shift(offset).
For example merge bitmap1(bigger) into bitmap2(smaller) starting offset 3.  Offset 3 mean that 3rd bit of bitmap1 corresponds to 0 bit of bitmap2.
By merge I mean logical Or operation. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Currently I have done this with simple uneffective for loop

```
const ulong BitsPerUlong = 64;



    MergeAt(ulong startIndex, Bitmap bitmap2)
    {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < bitmap2.Capacity; i++)
            {
                bool newVal = bitmap2.GetAt(i) | bitmap1.GetAt(i)
                bitmap2.SetAt(i, newVal) 
            }

      }

    bool GetAt(ulong index)
    {
        var dataOffset = BitOffsetToUlongOffset(index);
        ulong mask = 0x1ul << ((int)(index % BitsPerUlong));

        return (_data[dataOffset] & mask) == mask;
    }

    void SetAt(ulong index, bool value)
    {
        var dataOffset = BitOffsetToUlongOffset(index);
        ulong mask = 0x1ul << ((int)(index % BitsPerUlong));

        if (value)
        {
            _data[dataOffset] |= mask;
        }
        else
        {
            _data[dataOffset] &= ~mask;
        }
    }

    ulong BitOffsetToUlongOffset(ulong index)
    {
        var dataOffset = index / BitsPerUlong;

        return dataOffset;
    }
```

(C/C++/C# accepted).

Comment: can you show an attempt you made? Some pseudocode, or an implementation. I think a simple loop over the two arrays would suffice

Comment: @SimonHoubracken done

Answer (score 0):

As you probably figured out yourself, if `offset < BitsPerULong` the first block can be merged with:

```
data1[0] |= data2[0] << offset;
```

Which leaves some bits in `data2[0]` unmerged, but you can get those with:

```
data2[0] >> (BitsPerULong - offset)
```

So the next merge for `i > 0` becomes:

```
data1[i] |= (data2[i] << offset) | (data2[i-1] >> (BitsPerULong - offset));
```

from which you can construct a for-loop to merge all data. Of course, this still means a couple of bits from data2 will "fall off" but I think that's inherent to your problem description?

If you need a more generic solution where `offset` can also be greater than `BitsPerULong`, this needs a bit more work.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you mean that you want to "merge" the smaller INTO the bigger.

Have you tried:  **bitmapLarger |= ( bitmapSmaller << 3 )** ?

Comment: arrays doesn't support bitshift operation... doesn't they?